# CTE to loop until next TextData field present

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, sql-server-2016

Afternoon All,

Apologies immediately. I'm new to using CTE's and they still confuse the pickle out of me.

I'm currently working through some SQL Traces to identify an issue with an API call to our SQL environment and which suspect is causing an extensive delay.

I need to be able to identify how long each query ran for and what Statement Types were occurring. However, The query exists in an RPC:Starting Line (EventClass 11) and the duration/Statement types (ObjectName) exists in a QLTransaction line (EventClass 50) that occurs after the EventClass 11 line. To further complicate it i need the duration across all EventSubClasses and the Statement Type only when the EventSubClass is 0.

The following SQL Fiddle has a sample data range (I've had to redact the TextData for GDPR Purposes but each entry is distinct in this case there are dupolicates in the actual data) :- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/88857/4/1

The output I'm hoping to see is as follows:

```
RowNumber   EventClass  TextData            StartTime          ApplicationName  Duration    EndTime     EventSubClass   ObjectName
244         11          *** REDACTED 1 ***  18/06/2018 12:14   (null)           (null)      (null)      (null)          (null)
245         11          *** REDACTED 2 ***  18/06/2018 12:14   (null)           34791       (null)      (null)          CREATE TABLE, INSERT, sort_init, sort_init, DROPOBJ, FCheckAndCleanupCachedTempTable
258         11          *** REDACTED 3 ***  18/06/2018 12:14   (null)           (null)      (null)      (null)          (null)
261         11          *** REDACTED 4 ***  18/06/2018 12:14   (null)           (null)      (null)      (null)          (null)
262         11          *** REDACTED 5 ***  18/06/2018 12:14   (null)           (null)      (null)      (null)          (null)
263         11          *** REDACTED 6 ***  18/06/2018 12:14   (null)           12402       (null)      (null)          sort_init, sort_init
268         11          *** REDACTED 7 ***  18/06/2018 12:14   (null)           (null)      (null)      (null)          (null)
```

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to align the data in your sample data. That isn't easy to understand in its current format (unless the first line does have the value `'244 11 ***'` for `RowNumber` and `EventClass` has a value of `'REDACTED 1 *'`)

Comment: Sorry Larnu, Not so simple to put a grid in. Hope thats more clear now